# JavaScript How to calculate roadmap distance between 2 locations of lat longs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I Strucked while calculating RoadMap distance between 2 locations of lat longs using JavaScript.

Found answer :

with this link :

```
var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: [origin1],
destinations: [destinationA],
travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
avoidHighways: false,
avoidTolls: false
}, function(response, status) {
if (status !== google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
        alert('Error was: ' + status);
  return;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c6omLvso/

Comment: use google maps API to it's fullmost extent

Comment: Please, do not forget to mark my answer as an answer for your question. It will help others. thanks.

Comment: The link you are writing about is fiddle I made for you, so please do not forget to mark my answer as an answer. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the google maps javascript api? if so u can try the  ["Distance Matrix Service"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix)

Comment: Yes am using JavaScript only. can you give any example link.

Comment: the example they have given is https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix

Comment: in that both lat long and location name we giving input then if i have only lat long without name of location then how ?

Comment: `var destinationB = {lat: 50.087, lng: 14.421};`

you should be able to give it as above without the need for names i guess

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal using the google distance matrix like this:

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.53, 9.4),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  
    var origin1 = {lat: 55.93, lng: -3.118};
    var origin2 = 'Greenwich, England';
    var destinationA = 'Stockholm, Sweden';
    var destinationB = {lat: 50.087, lng: 14.421};
  
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [origin1, origin2],
        destinations: [destinationA, destinationB],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
    }, function(response, status) {
        if (status !== google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
            alert('Error was: ' + status);
            return;
        }

        var originList = response.originAddresses;
   var destinationList = response.destinationAddresses;
        var output = document.getElementById("output");
        output.innerHTML = "";
    
    for (var i = 0; i < originList.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
        output.innerHTML += originList[i] + ' to ' + destinationList[j] +
          ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in ' +
          results[j].duration.text + '<br>';
      }
    }    
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

#map {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks but...you giving  
    var origin1 = {lat: 55.93, lng: -3.118};
    var origin2 = 'Greenwich, England';
    var destinationA = 'Stockholm, Sweden';
    var destinationB = {lat: 50.087, lng: 14.421};

both lat long and name of location. i have only lat long with me then how ?

Comment: It is an example, just change the origin, and the destination to your desired ones.

Comment: You can use only `lng` and `lat` for both origin and destination.

Comment: Here is an fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c6omLvso/ with only one origin and one destination, using only `lng` and `lat`. Hope it will help

Comment: Your welcome. So please mark this as an answer. Thanks.